# SystemMediaTransportControls is not appearing in WP 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have been in a headache to display `SystemMediaTransportControls` in my wp8.1 app, unfortunately it doesn't work.
Here is the scenario, I have added Windows Phone App Project and then Windows Runtime Component (Windows Phone). I referenced the Runtime Component in My probject and then in the manifest added Audio as a Background Task. 
Everything seems to work fine, the media is played in the background, but the `SystemMediaTransportControls` are not displayed. Below is my code for Run method in my BackgroundTask

```
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Background Audio Task " + taskInstance.Task.Name + " starting...");

            taskInstance.Canceled += TaskInstance_Canceled;
            //taskInstance.Task.Completed += Taskcompleted;

            systemmediatransportcontrol = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
            systemmediatransportcontrol.ButtonPressed += systemmediatransportcontrol_ButtonPressed;
            systemmediatransportcontrol.PropertyChanged += systemmediatransportcontrol_PropertyChanged;

            systemmediatransportcontrol.IsEnabled = true;
            systemmediatransportcontrol.IsPauseEnabled = true;
            systemmediatransportcontrol.IsPlayEnabled = true;
            systemmediatransportcontrol.IsNextEnabled = true;
            systemmediatransportcontrol.IsPreviousEnabled = true;

            BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.CurrentStateChanged += Current_CurrentStateChanged;
            BackgroundMediaPlayer.MessageReceivedFromForeground += BackgroundMediaPlayer_MessageReceivedFromForeground;

            Debug.WriteLine(systemmediatransportcontrol.IsEnabled.ToString());

            ValueSet message = new ValueSet();
            message.Add("backgroundStarted", "1");
            BackgroundMediaPlayer.SendMessageToForeground(message);

            BackgroundTaskStarted.Set();
            deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        }
```

It has been two days working in this problem and it has given me a lot of headache. The question is, why `SystemMediaTransportControls` is not displayed?

Comment: Have you declared background task in appmanifest?

Comment: Add some code to your question

Comment: Thanks, I have added the backgroundTask Run method

Comment: @UtsavDawn yeah, I haved added, The only thing is the buttons doesn't appear while application is not running, but the audio is playing.

Answer (score 1):

Use SystemMediaTransportControls.DisplayUpdater to set the MusicProperties. MusicProperties is of type MusicDisplayProperties and include properties such as the song title and the song artist.
Update this on track change:

```
systemmediatransportcontrol.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Playing;
systemmediatransportcontrol.DisplayUpdater.Type = MediaPlaybackType.Music;
systemmediatransportcontrol.DisplayUpdater.MusicProperties.Title = "<Track_Name>";
systemmediatransportcontrol.DisplayUpdater.MusicProperties.Artist = "<Artist_Name>";
systemmediatransportcontrol.DisplayUpdater.Update();
```